# javascript validation - first capital only - how to?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
     // Validate Sentence Case
    if(dataEntryCaseId.toString().match("4")){
        var newValue = toTitleCase(value);
        if(newValue != value){
            for(var x = 1, j = value.length; x < j; x++){
                if(value.charAt(x) != newValue.charAt(x)){
                    valid = false;
                    $("#text_10").attr({"value":$("#text_10").attr("value").replace(value.charAt(x), "")});
                    finalVal = finalVal.replace(value.charAt(x), "");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if(!valid){
        for(var x = 0, j = styleNoteJsonData.styleGroupNote.length; x < j; x++){
            if(styleNoteJsonData.styleGroupNote[x].styleName == styleGroupName){
                alert(styleNoteJsonData.styleGroupNote[x].styleNote);
                $(".styleNote").addClass("alertRed");
                SendErrorMessage(styleNoteJsonData.styleGroupNote[x].styleNote);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $(".styleNote").removeClass("alertRed");
    }

    if(finalVal.length > 0){
        return true;
    }

    return valid;

}


function toTitleCase(str){

        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).replace(/\s/, '');


}
```

I need to rework this to only allow the first letter to be capitalized (it doesn't have to be)

I was trying to do this with regex - which i'm not sure is needed if the javascript validation was correct - seefunction toTitleCase(str)

regex seems overkill - but maybe because the current validation is using it, it might be easier to incorporate, but I wanted to see if their were other options within the parameters of the current code.

Comment: o_O. wow.. so many letters. please, be more concrete

Comment: The example code you gave requires us to reverse engineer a lot about how your application works. Could you pare down your example to a plain english description of how your validation mechanism works and the specific code that isn't working for you?

Comment: What are you validating? Can you provde an example: Input, expected output, current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. If you want to only keep the first uppercase, use this function:

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    return str.charAt(0)+str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Additional notes:
Add `str = str.replace(/\s/g,"");` before `return ...` when you want to remove all white-space characters.

If you only want to remove the beginning and ending whitespace characters, add `str = str.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"");` instead,